# Can I use React 17 components in an application that uses React 18?

Tags: reactjs

I have an application that uses React v18. I want to import a (React Component) package into this application, but this package uses React v17 - is this going to be ok?
How will dependency resolution work itself out?

Comment: What do you mean "uses"? Components don't normally _include_ React. Either they're compatible or not. What does the developer say? Have you tried?

Comment: The component package has react 17 as a peer dependency. My application has react 18 as a dependency.